# Cors header error with ajax request request

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, csrf

I am trying to make a ajax request to the musicbrainz api but keep getting a cors header error.

the error : `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/?xxxxxxx' from origin 'https://my_url' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-csrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

code

```
var $artist_encoded = encodeURIComponent($artist);
var $album_encoded = encodeURIComponent($album);

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release-group/?query=artist:%22" + $artist_encoded + "%22%20AND%20releasegroup:%22" + $album_encoded + "%22",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: myfunction
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading of resources. So you must add permission to client side(ajax request) to receive response from server side.

You can handle this issue by creating a new middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    // Cors middleware for allow api access from client side 'vue project' 
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','*')
        ;
    }
}
```

and register the new middleware in `kernel.php`:
in middleware array add:

```
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

in route middleware array add:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = ['cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

Finally implement this middleware into routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
//... your routes
});
```

As a result when adding:
`->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')`
it means that you allow any other origin to access your app. You could just add an array of specific routes which you want to access your app. In your case I think it's `['127.0.0.1:8000']`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// i hope it help you 
$.ajax({
  url: "https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/place/478558f9-a951-4067-ad91-e83f6ba63e74?inc=aliases",
    headers: {
            'Content-Type':'text/xml',
        }, 
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(text) {
 console.log(text)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```